# nginx cache reverse proxy not caching

Tags: caching, nginx

I have the following and it is not working, as my requests are not cached. Could you please identify what is wrong?

```
http {
        proxy_cache_path  /mint/cache  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC2:10m       inactive=24h  max_size=1g;
 server {
                listen 443 ssl;
                server_name cached-calls.domain.com;
                location /spaces {
                        index index.html index.htm;
                        charset utf-8;
                        proxy_pass https://preview.contentful.com/spaces;
                        proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie Cache-Control Expires;
                        proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
                        proxy_cache STATIC2;
                        proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
                        proxy_cache_methods GET;
                        proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;
                        proxy_cache_valid 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 226 300 301 302 303 304  305 10m;
                        proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                        proxy_redirect off;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_For;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "";
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;

                        proxy_connect_timeout 90s;
                        proxy_send_timeout 90s;
                        proxy_read_timeout 90s;
                        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
                        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
                        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
                        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
                        send_timeout 90s;

                }
        }
}
```

My Request is:

```
GET /spaces/&content_type=login&locale=en HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4201
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-XSRF-TOKEN: 831a018f-7919-4db5-a97c-778a9f6c088e
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:4201/en
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=831a018f-7919-4db5-a97c-778a9f6c088e; JSESSIONID=ECED92B3149D422AA6E26182498F2149; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.1.653346684.1497870993; _gid=GA1.1.720272175.1504510558
If-None-Match: W/"70fb2193558c29d410dd966b398d5357"
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
X-Powered-By: Express
access-control-allow-origin: *
server: nginx/1.10.2
date: Tue, 05 Sep 2017 06:57:40 GMT
connection: close
access-control-allow-headers: Accept,Accept-Language,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Length,Content-Range,Content-Type,DNT,Destination,Expires,If-Match,If-Modified-Since,If-None-Match,Keep-Alive,Last-Modified,Origin,Pragma,Range,User-Agent,X-Http-Method-Override,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With,X-Contentful-Version,X-Contentful-Content-Type,X-Contentful-Organization,X-Contentful-Skip-Transformation,X-Contentful-User-Agent,X-Contentful-Enable-Experimental-Feature
access-control-allow-methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS
access-control-expose-headers: Etag
access-control-max-age: 1728000
cf-cache-name: content_delivery
cf-organization-id: 123456
cf-space-id: 456789
etag: W/"987654"
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-contentful-request-id: 123456
```

This is proxied from localhost to cached-calls.domain.com using angular's proxy with this configuration:

```
  "/spaces" : {
    "target" : "https://cached-calls.domain.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/spaces/": "/spaces/spaceId/entries?access_token=accessToken"
    }
  }
```

Comment: You requre `localhost:4201` that is not nginx's host. So nginx has nothing to do with it

Comment: this is an angular app. localhost:4201/spaces is proxied to the domain under which nginx is

Comment: How is it proxied? Show

Comment: done. added proxy conf to question