# Nuxt.js, nginx project not caching

Tags: vue.js, nginx, caching, nuxt.js

Caching for my website is not working.

Website:
https://flowerqueen.ro/. I am checking caching on right click -> inspect -> aplication ->storage (Google Chrome)

Checked this solution [nginx cache reverse proxy not caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048819/nginx-cache-reverse-proxy-not-caching) but without results.
My nginx default conf:

```
 server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; 
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_cache cache;
            proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 12h;

            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

            proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie;
            proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
            proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;

            proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
       }
    location ^~ /images {
            proxy_cache cache;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 12h;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
  http {
    proxy_cache_path /tmp/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:10m inactive=60m;
    proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##


    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 4048;
    # server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 5M;
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

nuxt.config

```
  import shrinkRay from 'shrink-ray-current'
  export default {
       ssr: false,
       mode: 'spa',
       target: 'server',
       server: {
       port: 3000,
       host: 'localhost',
     },

     render: {
       compressor: shrinkRay()
     },
   
modules: [// Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
'@nuxtjs/axios',
'vue-scrollto/nuxt',
'nuxt-robots',
[
  '@nuxtjs/component-cache',
  {
    max: 10000,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60
  }
],
'@nuxtjs/proxy',
[
  'nuxt-i18n',
  {
    parsePages: false,
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        iso: 'en-GB',
        name: 'english',
        file: 'en.js',
      },
      {
        code: 'ro',
        iso: 'ro-RO',
        name: 'romanian',
        file: 'ro.js',
      },
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'ro',
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: 'ro',
      messages: {
        en: require('./lang/en').default,
        ro: require('./lang/ro').default,
      },
    },
    lazy: false,
    langDir: 'lang/',
  },
 ],
],
```

I don't know what to try to make it working anymore, spent more then 5 hours already trying different configurations for nuxt and nginx and nothing helps. Can anyone help me solve this puzzle?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @xperator Not yet :(

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of playing around I have understood that I were looking into the wrong direction :)

Images were not caching because my frontend was served on one config (which I were modifying) but the real place from where the images were loaded was the backend. After adding those lines of code to my backend `nginx` config, everything started working as a charm.

before  `server {`

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
  default                       off;
  text/html                  epoch;
  text/css                   max;
  application/javascript     max;
  ~productImage/             max;
}
```

and inside `server`

```
  location ~* \.(webp|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
     expires 365d;
  }
```